# How to find difference between first and last values partitionby a columns in pyspark

Tags: python, pyspark

I have a dataframe like this:

```
+---------+-----+----+-----------------------+                                  
|label |value|unit|dateTime               |
+---------+-----+----+-----------------------+
|Uiqcnt|475  |    |2020-04-11T21:35:13.410|
|Uiqcnt|475  |    |2020-04-11T21:35:13.910|
|Uiqcnt|475  |    |2020-04-11T21:35:14.400|
|Uiqcnt|476  |    |2020-04-11T21:35:14.910|
|Uiqcnt|476  |    |2020-04-11T21:35:15.400|
|Uiqcnt|476  |    |2020-04-11T21:35:15.910|
|Uiqcnt|477  |    |2020-04-11T21:35:16.410|
|Uiqcnt|477  |    |2020-04-11T21:35:16.910|
|Uiqcnt|477  |    |2020-04-11T21:35:17.420|
|Uiqcnt|478  |    |2020-04-11T21:35:17.920|
|Uiqcnt|478  |    |2020-04-11T21:35:18.430|
```

I want get the time difference partition by value. Considering large amount of data how can I do this in most efficient way?

Comment: @anky yes.For this case there will be 4 rows for value =475,476,477,478 with the difference between first and last datetime value

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can group the dataset by `value` and the calculate the min and max dates. After that you can calculate the difference between the min and the max. I assume that the results can be rounded to a second so that `to_unixtimestamp` can be used.

```python
df.groupBy("value").agg(F.min("dateTime").alias("min"), F.max("dateTime").alias("max")) \
    .withColumn("minUnix", F.unix_timestamp(F.col("min"))) \
    .withColumn("maxUnix", F.unix_timestamp(F.col("max"))) \
    .withColumn("diff", F.col("maxUnix") - F.col("minUnix")) \
    .select("value", "diff") \
```

If you need also the fractions of seconds, a udf can help:

```python
time_delta = F.udf(lambda min, max: (max-min).total_seconds(), FloatType())

df.groupBy("value").agg(F.min("dateTime").alias("min"), F.max("dateTime").alias("max")) \
    .withColumn("diff",  time_delta(F.col("min"),F.col("max"))) \
    .show(truncate=False)
```

prints

```
+-----+----------------------+----------------------+----+
|value|min                   |max                   |diff|
+-----+----------------------+----------------------+----+
|476  |2020-04-11 21:35:14.91|2020-04-11 21:35:15.91|1.0 |
|477  |2020-04-11 21:35:16.41|2020-04-11 21:35:17.42|1.01|
|478  |2020-04-11 21:35:17.92|2020-04-11 21:35:18.43|0.51|
|475  |2020-04-11 21:35:13.41|2020-04-11 21:35:14.4 |0.99|
+-----+----------------------+----------------------+----+
```